# Is there a way to move a column in between existing columns with drag-and-drop?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I want to move a column with some data to be in between two existing columns which also have data.  However, a simple drag-and-drop of the column will just prompt me to replace the data of whichever column is closest to the drop.

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or other equally-efficient method, that will allow me to perform a fairly simple drag-and-drop to in between columns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hold shift and the shaded border you see when moving the selected column will change to a shaded line between two destination columns.

When you release your mouse the column will move to where the shaded line was.

Answer (score 12):

The procedure is yet explained, but not in the exact way:

1. first, press over the column name to have it selected.
2. second, while pressing shift, move the mouse pointer over the top-left corner of the first cell, until it gets to a cross arrows symbol ( like this: http://www.getfreeimage.com/image/719/mouse-pointer ).
3. Then, click and drag the column to its new position.
4. That's all.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Excel 14.1.4 and this is the keyboard shortcut I use to move columns:

1. **CLICK** the *column* name to select for moving.
2. **MOVE** the *cursor* to the left or right line of the selected column until the cursor changes to the 'grab hand' tool.
3. **HOLD** the *shift* key.
4. **CLICK** the *line*.
5. **DRAG** the *column* to line between the columns where you want to insert the moved column. (The the name of the column being movedwill change to X:X, indicating the name of the column to the *right* of the column being moved.)
6. **DROP** the *column* in the new position.

NOTE: If you don't hold **SHIFT**, the column being move will overwrite the existing column when dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Office 2010. The only way I've been able to move a column is to

1. Insert a new column where I want to move to
2. Cut the column I want to move
3. Inserting it into the new column.

For some reason the above does not work for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but this is what worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Excel 2010. The only way I've been able to move a column is to

1. Insert a new column where I want to move to
2. Right click on column you want to move
3. Select- entire column
4. Drag left/right side of column to new location
5. New column remains

I have been able to move several columns at once

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you want to move Column *A* to between Column *G* and *H*

1. Right Click Column *A* Heading
2. Click on **Cut**
3. Right Click Column *H* Heading.
4. Click on **Insert Cut Cells**.

You can do this with Multiple Columns as well but they must be adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the row or column that you want to move or copy.
2. To select rows or columns, do one of the following:

   - To move rows or columns, click Cut on the Standard toolbar, or press CTRL+X.
   - To copy rows or columns, click Copy on the Standard toolbar, or press CTRL+C
3. Select a row or column below or to the right of where you want to move or copy your selection
4. Do one of the following:

   - When you are moving rows or columns, click Cut Cells on the Insert menu
   - When you are copying rows or columns, click Copied Cells on the Insert menu

Note:   If you click Paste on the Standard toolbar or press CTRL+V instead of clicking a command on the Insert menu, you will replace any contents of the destination cells.